# Overlay tutorial appears behind main UI (Android)

Tags: android, user-interface, android-xml

### The problem

In one of my apps I use a Tutorial overaly view ([TapTargetView](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView)) which at the first opening of the app shows a nice tutorial to the user.
On most devices this works fine, except for some users the overlay is **behind** the normal user interface creating a view like in the below image:
*The phone here is a OnePlus 1, CyanogenOS 12.1 (Lollipop).*

[image]

The issue also occured with another Tutorial overlay Library ([ShowcaseView](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView)).

### Code

The tutorial code is as follows:

```
TapTargetSequence intro = new TapTargetSequence(this)
                    .targets(
                            TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.btnSearchEverything), "Search all", "Search for Spells, Items and other content here.")
                                    // All options below are optional
                                    .outerCircleColor(R.color.selectedred)      
                                    .targetCircleColor(R.color.lightgreen)   
                                    .titleTextSize(20)                 
                                    .titleTextColor(R.color.styletext)
                                    .descriptionTextSize(14) 
                                    .descriptionTextColor(R.color.styletext) 
                                    .textColor(R.color.styletext)  
                                    .cancelable(true) 
                                    .tintTarget(false)
                                    .transparentTarget(true)
                                    .targetRadius(60),
                            TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.btnForum), "Share content", "Share and import content from our forums.")
                                    .outerCircleColor(R.color.selectedred)     
                                    .targetCircleColor(R.color.lightgreen)  
                                    .titleTextSize(20)
                                    .titleTextColor(R.color.styletext)
                                    .descriptionTextSize(14)
                                    .descriptionTextColor(R.color.styletext)
                                    .textColor(R.color.styletext)       
                                    .cancelable(true)
                                    .transparentTarget(true) 
                                    .targetRadius(120), 
                            TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.btnCreator), "Content Creator", "With the online content tools you can easily add your own homebrew content.")

                                    .outerCircleColor(R.color.selectedred)     
                                    .targetCircleColor(R.color.lightgreen)   
                                    .targetRadius(120));
            intro.start();
```

The following XML is the relevant part of the user interface (I left out all the buttons for ease of reading since I am quite sure it doesn't matter for the issue).

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".StartschermActivity"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:text="@string/welkom" />


 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If anyone has any idea how this effect can occur and more importantly how to possibly solve this, I would love to know.
If it would be HTML I would say to increase a z-index somewhere but since its Android and the tutorial appears **later** than the main UI, I have no clue how to fix it.

--

### Update

The view hiearchy as shown by the Android Studio inspector is:
[image]

Comment: Have you check the view index in inside the viewParent, by using the Hierarchy view?

Comment: I have updated the question, for all I see the view hierarchy is fine.

Comment: Is this simulator or the device with problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have no access to the device with the problem since its not mine. That also makes debugging more difficult.

Comment: (Its a real device that has the problem)